# Find windows user name within R

Tags: windows, r

Is there a way to get the current windows user name or the windows home within an R session?

Thanks.
(Sorry, if I missed something, but I couldn't find anything)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can do

```
Sys.getenv("USERNAME")
Sys.getenv("HOME")
```

And if you just type

```
Sys.getenv()
```

you will see all available environment variables.

Comment: Sys.getenv() by itself produces a fairly unreadable result.  You can get all of the variable names with names(Sys.getenv()), and look up those that are interesting.

Comment: You can use `as.list(Sys.getenv())` to make it more readable.

Answer (score 40):

I prefer this

```
Sys.info()[["user"]]
```

Comment: This works on Linux as well (tested on CentOS 6, R version 3.3)

Answer (score 7):

If you know how to do it at your system console, the answer would generally be:

```
system("...that_string...")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the path to the current user's home directory, try:

```r
> dirname("~")
[1] "C:/Users/username
```