# Download Covid patient metadata from GISAID website in R using RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I would like to download a particular file with Covid patient metadata from the public [GISAID website](https://www.gisaid.org/) (Login button, https://www.epicov.org/epi3/start) and I would like to automate this so I can do this from R & automatically produce daily updates etc of my analyses.
I thought I would be able to do this using a web browser automation tool like `RSelenium`, but I am stumbling at a problem where I have to click a checkbox and then press a Download button, and that last part of the code doesn't work.

What I have so far, and what is working so far is

```
library(RSelenium)
chr = wdman::chrome(port = 4572L, version="102.0.5005.61", check=FALSE) 
# run one time with check=TRUE and then
# delete ..//Users/XXXX/AppData/Local/binman/binman_chromedriver/win32/103.0.5060.24
# and download and install chrome 102.0.5005.63 from https://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions 
# and re-run with check=FALSE
# to avoid version mismatches between chrome and chromedriver
# TO DO: elegant fix for this welcome, see
# https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/221

eCaps = list(chromeOptions = list(
  args = c(# '--headless', # unmark for headless operation
           '--no-sandbox', 
           '--disable-dev-shm-usage', 
           '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
           'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
           )
))
remDr = remoteDriver(port = 4572L, 
                     version="102.0.5005.61", 
                     browserName = "chrome", 
                     extraCapabilities = eCaps)
remDr$open()

# TO DO: set download directory, see 
# https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/138
# otherwise default download directory would be used
# advice here also welcome
  
# clicking Login on https://www.gisaid.org/
# gets one to https://www.epicov.org/epi3/start
# so we start there
remDr$navigate("https://www.epicov.org/epi3/start")
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)
remDr$getTitle()

# enter credentials
username = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id='elogin']")
username$sendKeysToElement(list("USERNAME"))
# PUT GISAID USERNAME HERE (EVERYONE CAN REGISTER)

password = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id='epassword']")
password$sendKeysToElement(list("PASSWORD"))
# PUT GISAID PASSWORD HERE (EVERYONE CAN REGISTER)

# click Login buttom
login_button = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@value='Login']")
login_button$clickElement() 

remDr$getCurrentUrl()

epicov_tab = remDr$findElement("xpath", "//a[contains(text(),'EpiCoV™')]")
epicov_tab$click()

downloads_tab = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-actionbar-action-ni")[[3]]
downloads_tab$clickElement()    
remDr$getCurrentUrl()

# switch to right frame
frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)

# available download buttons
download_buttons = remDr$findElements("class", "kachel75")
length(download_buttons) # 26 downloads available in total

# download patient metadata
metadata_button = download_buttons[[12]] # patient metadata
metadata_button$click()
```

At this point a window with a checkbox pops up.
All the steps above all work (except for the installation problems where there is a chrome & chromedriver version mismatch, which is a known issue in `RSelenium`, https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/221, which I had to solve by manually deleting one of the installed versions, and the fact that I still don't know how to set a custom download directory rather than just use the default download directory), but I don't manage to get past this window with this checkbox. What I tried was

```
remDr$getCurrentUrl() # https://www.epicov.org/epi3/frontend#2f475c

# switch to right frame
frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)

checkbox = remDr$findElements("xpath", "//input[@type='checkbox']")
checkbox$click()
Sys.sleep(5)

download = remDr$findElements("xpath", 
                              "//button[contains(.,'Download')]")
download$click()

# then we would still have to move and unzip resulting *.tar.xz file

# and quit
remDr$close()
chr$stop()
remDr$quit()
```

but the `checkbox$click()` gives me an error "Error: attempt to apply non-function" and then `download$click()` also doesn't work...

The HTML code of this last page with this checkbox is

```
<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n<meta content=\"IE=EmulateIE8\" http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\">\n<meta content=\"GISAID actively promotes the sharing of virus sequences, related clinical and epidemiological data associated with human isolates, and geographic and species-specific data associated with avian and other animal isolates.\" name=\"description\">\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'entities/files/js/ckeditor/';\n</script>\n<meta content=\"GISAID, GISAID Initiative, COVID-19, EpiCoV, EpiFlu, EpiRSV, Global Health Security, Real-Time Disease Surveillance\" name=\"keywords\">\n<meta content=\"noindex\" name=\"robots\">\n<style type=\"text/css\">\nbody {\n    margin: 0;\n}\n#c_rdj376_1bg {\n    position: absolute;\n    width: 100%;\n    height: 100%;\n    margin: auto;\n}\n#c_rdj376_1bh {\n    position: absolute;\n    top: 0px;\n    right: 0px;\n    bottom: 60px;\n    left: 0px;\n    overflow: auto;\n    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;\n}\n#c_rdj376_1bj {\n    position: absolute;\n    bottom: 0;\n    left: 0;\n    right: 0;\n    height:  60px;\n}\n</style>\n<title>GISAID Initiative</title>\n<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_q3/combined_std.css\">\n<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_q4/combined_std.css\">\n<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_26g/combined_std.css\">\n<script language=\"JavaScript\" type=\"text/javascript\">\nfunction loadScript(u,c) {\n//alert(\"Loading \" + u)\n\tvar s=document.createElement(\"script\");\n\ts.type=\"text/javascript\";\n\tif (s.readyState) {\n\t\ts.onreadystatechange = function() {\n\t\t\tif (s.readyState == \"loaded\" || s.readyState == \"complete\") {\n\t\t\t\ts.onreadystatechange=null;\n\t\t\t\tc();\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t};\n\t} else {\n\t\ts.onload = function() {\n\t\t\tc()\n\t\t}\n\t};\n\ts.src = u;\n\tdocument.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0].appendChild(s)\n};\n\nvar full_page_load_responses = [];\n\nloadScript(\"/epi3/entities/files/js/sys.js?no_cache=1655312378.13\",function(){sys[\"SID\"] = \"B485F3DEYKSGHX7ZWG8MP234FLP5FFLI\";sys[\"WID\"] = \"wid_rdj376_9b3y\";sys[\"PID\"] = \"pid_rdj376_9b3z\";sys[\"UID\"] = \"291260\";sys[\"is_development_mode\"] = false;sys[\"testrunner_active\"] = false;sys[\"page_name\"] = \"\";sys[\"msgs\"] = new Object({'txt_disable_popupblocker':' Please disable popup-blocker!'});loadScript(\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_q1/combined_std.js\",function(){loadScript(\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_1os/combined_std.js\",function(){loadScript(\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_1z7/combined_std.js\",function(){if(document.readyState=='loaded'||document.readyState=='complete'){sys.handleDomReady();}else{window.onload=sys.handleDomReady;}});});});sys.onPageInit(function(){sys.createComponent('c_rdj376_1bk','Corona2020DownloadReminderButtonsComponent',new Object({'buttons':'c_rdj376_1bj-c_rdj376_1bk','__main__':'c_rdj376_1bk-c_rdj376_1bk'}),\"FormComponent\",\"\",function(){this.getForm().createFI('ce_rdj376_16f','LinesetWidget','checkit',function(){this.getForm().createFI('ce_rdj376_16g','CheckboxWidget','agreed',function(){this.setParams(new Object({'on_change':'Agreed','has_help':false}));}); }); this.getForm().createFI('ce_rdj376_16h','ButtonsWidget','ce_rdj376_16h',function(){this.getForm().createFI('ce_rdj376_16i','ButtonWidget','back',function(){this.setParams(new Object({'on_change':null,'has_help':false,'cmd':'Back'}));\n }); this.getForm().createFI('ce_rdj376_16j','ButtonWidget','downbtn',function(){this.setParams(new Object({'on_change':null,'has_help':false,'cmd':'Download'}));\n }); }); });});sys.onPageInit(function(){sys.createComponent('c_rdj376_1bi','Corona2020DownloadReminderComponent',new Object({'__main__':'c_rdj376_1bi-c_rdj376_1bi'}),\"CanvasComponent\",\"\",function(){function ccc() {\n    var els = document.getElementsByTagName(\"INPUT\");\n    for (idx in els) {\n        if (els[idx].type == \"checkbox\") {\n            if (!els[idx].checked) {\n                alert(\"You must first agree to the terms and conditions\")\n                return false;\n            }\n        }\n    }\n    return;\n}\n\n });});sys.onPageInit(function() {new sys.Packer(\"c_rdj376_1bg\", \"c_rdj376_1bh\");new LegacyHandler();\n        var resizeTimer;\n        $(window).resize(function() {\n           clearTimeout(resizeTimer);\n           resizeTimer = setTimeout(sys.handleAfterWindowResize, 100);\n        });\n        sys.showInitiallyHiddens();\n        \n        setTimeout(function() { sys.executeFullPageLoadResponses(); }, 500);\n\t});if(sys[\"testrunner_active\"]){sys.testrunner_activatePage();};\n});\n</script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/epi3/entities/files/js/sys.js?no_cache=1655312378.13\"></script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_q1/combined_std.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_1os/combined_std.js\"></script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/epi3/entities/tmp//static/_rdj376_1z7/combined_std.js\"></script></head>\n<body marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" topmargin=\"0\" leftmargin=\"0\" style=\"text-align:left;\" onbeforeunload=\"sys.handleUnloadPage()\" class=\"yui-skin-sam\">\n<form class=\"sys-form\">\n<input style=\"display:none\" name=\"dummy\" type=\"entry\"><button id=\"sys_focus_button\" type=\"button\" style=\"display: none;\"></button>\n<div id=\"sys_devmenu\">\n<img title=\"Clear caches and reload page\" onclick=\"sys.devmenu_reloadApplication(false, null, true)\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" align=\"absmiddle\" src=\"/epi3/entities/files/icons//sys_recache.gif\"><img title=\"Reload page\" onclick=\"sys.devmenu_reloadApplication(false)\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" align=\"absmiddle\" src=\"/epi3/entities/files/icons//sys_reload.gif\"><img title=\"Reload page and reset work setup\" onclick=\"sys.devmenu_reloadApplication(true)\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" align=\"absmiddle\" src=\"/epi3/entities/files/icons//sys_reset.png\"><span id=\"sys_devmenu_info\"></span><img title=\"Run tests\" onclick=\"sys.devmenu_startTestRunner()\" style=\"cursor:pointer;margin-left:5px\" align=\"absmiddle\" src=\"/epi3/entities/files/icons//testrunner_24.png\"></div>\n<div style=\"display:none\" id=\"testrunner_indicator\">\n<img style=\"position:absolute;top:30px;left:30px\" src=\"/epi3/entities/files/icons//testrunner_large.png\"></div>\n<div id=\"sys_curtain\" class=\"sys_curtain\" onclick=\"sys.handleCurtainClick()\" style=\"display: none; opacity: 0;\"></div>\n<div id=\"sys_timer\" class=\"sys_timer\" style=\"display: none;\">\n<div class=\"sys_timer_inner\">\n<img class=\"sys_timer_img\" src=\"/epi3/entities/files/icons//sys_timer.gif\"><div id=\"sys_timer_message\" class=\"sys_timer_message\"></div>\n<div style=\"margin-top: 20px; display: none;\" id=\"sys_timer_gauge\" class=\"sys_timer_gauge\"></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div style=\"width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto\" class=\"page\">\n        \n<div id=\"c_rdj376_1bg\" class=\"packer\">\n            \n<div style=\"top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 60px; left: 0px;\" scrollpositions=\",\" id=\"c_rdj376_1bh\" class=\"main container-slot\">\n                \n<div cid=\"c_rdj376_1bi\" class=\"sys-component-slot\" id=\"c_rdj376_1bi-c_rdj376_1bi\">\n<div style=\"padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px; margin-top:15px\">\n\n\n<b>NOTICE AND REMINDER of TERMS OF USE:</b>\n<br clear=\"none\">\n\n<p>The <a href=\"https://www.gisaid.org/DAA\" shape=\"rect\" target=\"daa\">Terms of Use</a> you agreed to when requesting access credentials to GISAID include the following:\n</p>\n<p>1) You will not distribute, redistribute, share, or otherwise make available Data, to any third party or the public, unless the individual is an Authorized User of GISAID;\n<br clear=\"none\">2) You will not display Data, in whole or in part, on any website, media material, or as part of a service, without GISAID’s express written permission;\n<br clear=\"none\">3) You will treat all Data contained in these files consistent with other Data in GISAID and in accordance with the GISAID Database Access Agreement (“DAA”);\n<br clear=\"none\">4) You will provide proper attributions, acknowledgements, and make best efforts to collaborate consistent with the DAA when using Data in any publication, including preprints, manuscripts, articles, and any other analyses.\n<br clear=\"none\">\n\n</p>\n<p>\nBy checking this box you reaffirm your understanding, and assent to, the <a href=\"https://www.gisaid.org/DAA\" shape=\"rect\" target=\"daa\">Terms of Use</a>\n</p>\n\n\n</div>\n</div>\n            \n</div>\n            \n<div style=\"width: 100%; height: 60px;\" id=\"c_rdj376_1bj\" class=\"buttons container-slot\">\n                \n<div cid=\"c_rdj376_1bk\" class=\"sys-component-slot\" id=\"c_rdj376_1bk-c_rdj376_1bk\">\n<div id=\"ce_rdj376_16f\">\n<table class=\"sys-form-firow\" style=\"width:98%;\">\n<tbody><tr>\n<td class=\"sys-form-cfilabel\" colspan=\"1\" rowspan=\"1\" style=\"width:150px\">\n\t\t\n<div class=\"sys-form-filabel sys-form-filabel\"></div>\n\t\n</td><td colspan=\"1\" rowspan=\"1\" style=\"float:right\">\n\t\t\n<table class=\"sys-form-filine\">\n<tbody><tr>\n<td class=\"sys-form-filine-td\" colspan=\"1\" rowspan=\"1\" style=\"\">\n\t\t\n<div id=\"ce_rdj376_16g\">\n<div class=\"sys-form-fi-cb sys-fi-mark\">\n        \n<div style=\"float:left;;margin-right:3px;white-space: nowrap;\">\n       \n<input class=\"sys-event-hook\" name=\"ce_rdj376_16g_name\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"agreed\"><span class=\"\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\">I agree to the terms and conditions</span>\n   \n</div>\n\t\n</div>\n\n<div class=\"sys-form-fi-message-cnt\">\n<div class=\"sys-form-fi-message\" id=\"ce_rdj376_16g_msg\"></div>\n</div>\n</div>\t\n</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody></table>\t\n</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody></table>\n</div>\n</div>\n            \n<div cid=\"c_rdj376_1bk\" class=\"sys-component-slot\" id=\"c_rdj376_1bj-c_rdj376_1bk\">\n<div id=\"ce_rdj376_16h\">\n<div id=\"ce_rdj376_16i\">\n<div style=\"float: left\">\n\t\n<button class=\"sys-event-hook sys-form-button\" style=\"\" title=\"\" type=\"button\"><img align=\"absmiddle\" class=\"sys-form-button-icon\" src=\"/epi3/app_entities/entities/icons/24x24/navigate_left.png\">Back</button>\n\n</div>\n</div>\n<div id=\"ce_rdj376_16j\">\n<div style=\"float: right\">\n\t\n<button class=\"sys-event-hook sys-form-button\" disabled=\"\" style=\"\" title=\"\" type=\"button\"><img align=\"absmiddle\" class=\"sys-form-button-icon\" src=\"/epi3/app_entities/entities/icons/24x24/data_down.png\">Download</button>\n\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n        \n</div>\n    \n</div>\n</form>\n\n\n<div id=\"cboxOverlay\" style=\"display: none;\"></div><div id=\"colorbox\" class=\"\" style=\"display: none;\"><div id=\"cboxWrapper\"><div><div id=\"cboxTopLeft\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxTopCenter\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxTopRight\" style=\"float: left;\"></div></div><div style=\"clear: left;\"><div id=\"cboxMiddleLeft\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxContent\" style=\"float: left;\"><div id=\"cboxLoadedContent\" style=\"width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxLoadingOverlay\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxLoadingGraphic\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxTitle\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxCurrent\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxNext\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxPrevious\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxSlideshow\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxClose\" style=\"float: left;\"></div></div><div id=\"cboxMiddleRight\" style=\"float: left;\"></div></div><div style=\"clear: left;\"><div id=\"cboxBottomLeft\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxBottomCenter\" style=\"float: left;\"></div><div id=\"cboxBottomRight\" style=\"float: left;\"></div></div></div><div style=\"position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; display: none;\"></div></div></body></html>
```

Any thoughts?

Was also wondering what could be the reason that using `wdman::phantomjs` instead of `wdman::chrome` doesn't appear to work (links not followed etc). Is that common, and could that be fixed? As `phantomjs` is easier to install than `chrome` within `RSelenium` (no annoying version conflicts as with `chrome`)...

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Belgium.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Belgium.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Belgium.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Belgium.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RSelenium_1.7.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3     XML_3.99-0.10    binman_0.1.2     ps_1.7.0        
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1 bitops_1.0-7     rappdirs_0.3.3   R6_2.5.1        
 [9] jsonlite_1.8.0   semver_0.2.0     httr_1.4.3       curl_4.3.2      
[13] tools_4.2.0      wdman_0.2.5      yaml_2.3.5       compiler_4.2.0  
[17] processx_3.6.0   askpass_1.1      caTools_1.18.2   openssl_2.0.2
```

Comment: cn u pls provide the page html or the login credentials so that i can reach till that page

Comment: @SonaliDas I put the HTML code of that last page there if that helps? (GISAID terms don't allow to share login, but anyone can register for an account)

Comment: Yes the "I agree to the terms and conditions" is a checkbox, and when checked the download button becomes visible.  But just found a working solution actually, so I think I am sorted: checkbox = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-event-hook")[[1]]
checkbox$clickElement() 
Sys.sleep(5)
download = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-form-button-icon")[[2]]
download$clickElement()

Comment: @TomWenseleers - could you post your solution as an answer to your own question? It will help others who come across this issue.

Comment: @Roger-123 Yes I will do - hadn't gotten round to it yet, but will do!

Comment: @Roger-123 Put my working solution above as an edit. Still issues to get that to work in headless mode & to set download directory, but for the rest it works.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a hidden API instead of web scraping it directly?

Comment: @econbernardo There is no proper API unfortunately. I also have been granted access to a JSON data stream - but that's a huge file, so not overly practical - and also not generally accessible to other researchers. Which is why I also wanted to be able to download the file above, which is available to all registered users...

Comment: @TomWenseleers I don't know if we are talking about the same thing, but it may be worthwhile to give [this video](https://youtu.be/DqtlR0y0suo) a look to understand what I mean by "hidden API".

Comment: @econbernardo Oh, thanks - but I fear I'm not well enough into this sort of stuff to be able to figure that out... Anyway, given that I am mainly interested in being able to download the whole database in a single file for a single global analysis of all the data I think the above will do... But thanks for this - interesting stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the mistake in the end, the following code below works, either headless or not (obtained by unmarking `# '--headless',` below). Using the `phantomjs` browser instead didn't work, but apparently that's common, and found a good way to avoid the chromedriver version conflicts.

```
# note: set GISAID access credentials first using ####
# Sys.setenv(GISAIDR_USERNAME = "XXX") # GISAID username
# Sys.setenv(GISAIDR_PASSWORD = "XXX") # GISAID password
# put these commands in a file set_GISAID_credentials.R
# and then source that one first
# source(".//set_GISAID_credentials.R")

library(locatexec)

download_GISAD_meta = function(target_dir = getwd(), 
                               clean_up = FALSE,
                               headless = FALSE,
                               genom_epidem = FALSE, # if TRUE use Genomic Epidemiology Metadata package download, else use regular Metadata package download  
                               chromedriver_version = as.character(unlist(binman::list_versions("chromedriver")))[grepl(as.character(locatexec::exec_version("chrome")[[1, 1]]), as.character(unlist(binman::list_versions("chromedriver"))))][[1]], # or specify correct version, e.g. "104.0.5112.79"
                               usr = Sys.getenv("GISAIDR_USERNAME"),  
                               psw = Sys.getenv("GISAIDR_PASSWORD")) {
  # TO DO: also implement arguments clean_up=TRUE to delete downloaded file (default best set to FALSE though)
  # and get_sequence=TRUE to also download FASTA with sequences & add those to outputted dataframe
  
  require(RSelenium)
  require(readr)
  require(archive)
  require(data.table)
  require(dplyr)
  
  if (!dir.exists(target_dir)) dir.create(target_dir)
                              
arg = c('--no-sandbox', 
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage', 
        '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
        'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
)
if (headless) { arg = c('--headless', arg) } # for headless operation
eCaps = list(chromeOptions = list(
  args = arg,
  prefs = list(
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads" = 1L,
    "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
    "download.directory_upgrade" = TRUE,
    "safebrowsing.enabled" = TRUE,
    "safebrowsing.disable_download_protection" = TRUE,
    "useAutomationExtension" = FALSE,
    "default_directory" = normalizePath(target_dir)
  )
))
browser = wdman::chrome(port = 4570L, version = chromedriver_version, check = TRUE) 
remDr = remoteDriver(port = 4570L, 
                     version=chromedriver_version,
                     browserName = "chrome", 
                     extraCapabilities = eCaps)
remDr$open()
# note: if you get a message This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version xxx
# then make sure that you have specified the right chromedriver version 
# (check if installed chrome version matches some version available under binman/binman_chromedriver/XXX which ones get installed)
# it may be necessary to downgrade your Chrome browser to version xxx using instructions at
# https://browserhow.com/how-to-downgrade-and-install-older-version-of-chrome/#download-the-older-chrome-version
# download browser install from https://filehippo.com/download_google-chrome/history/
# and disable chrome updates

# code below needed in headless mode
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504731/specify-download-folder-in-rselenium
remDr$queryRD(
  ipAddr = paste0(remDr$serverURL, "/session/", remDr$sessionInfo[["id"]], "/chromium/send_command"),
  method = "POST",
  qdata = list(
    cmd = "Page.setDownloadBehavior",
    params = list(
      behavior = "allow",
      downloadPath = normalizePath(target_dir)
    )
  )
)

if (genom_epidem) { message("Downloading GISAID genomic epidemiology metadata...") } else { message("Downloading GISAID metadata...") }

remDr$navigate("https://www.epicov.org/epi3/start") 
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 100)

# enter credentials
username = NULL
while (length(username)==0) username = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id='elogin']")
username$sendKeysToElement(list(usr))
password = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id='epassword']")
password$sendKeysToElement(list(psw))

# click Login buttom
login_button = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@value='Login']")
login_button$clickElement() 

epicov_tab = NULL
while (length(epicov_tab)==0) { 
  suppressMessages(tryCatch({
    epicov_tab = remDr$findElement("xpath", "//a[contains(text(),'EpiCoV™')]") 
  }, error = function( err ) { epicov_tab = NULL })) }
epicov_tab$click()

downloads_tab = NULL
while (length(downloads_tab)==0) downloads_tab = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-actionbar-action-ni")[[3]]
downloads_tab$clickElement()

# switch to right frame
frames = NULL
while (length(frames)==0) frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)

# available download buttons
download_buttons = NULL
while (length(download_buttons)==0) download_buttons = remDr$findElements("class", "kachel75")
# length(download_buttons) # 26 downloads available in total

# sapply(download_buttons, function(d) d$findChildElement("class", "downicon"))

downicons = remDr$findElements("class", "downicon")
downicons_titles = unlist(sapply(downicons, function (d) d$getElementAttribute('title')))

linkicons = remDr$findElements("class", "linkicon")
linkicons_titles = unlist(sapply(linkicons, function (d) d$getElementAttribute('title')))

# TO DO: figure out all titles, in the order in which they appear on the Downloads page
# all_titles = XXX
  
download_nr_gisaid_meta = which(grepl("TSV-File", downicons_titles))+
  sum(linkicons_titles %in% c("Audacity files archive","LANL"))
download_nr_gisaid_genom_epidem_meta = which(grepl("metadata_", downicons_titles)) +
  sum(linkicons_titles %in% c("Audacity files archive", 
                              "LANL",
                              "FASTA and Metadata per clade",
                              "FASTA and Metadata per lineage",      
                              "Global Phylogeny",
                              "Select input for the Augur pipeline"))

# TO DO : get titles of <div class="downicon" onclick="sys.call('c_rg1kzy_13e','DownloadFile',new Object({'id':'gisaid:metadata_tsv.tar.xz'}));" title="TSV-File (2022-08-01)">
# <img src="/epi3/app_entities/entities/corona2020/download_other2.png"><div>metadata</div>
#   </div>

# TO DO: check version available for download & if already downloaded don't download it again
# allow downloading FASTA or other available download packages


# DOWNLOAD PATIENT METADATA (EITHER REGULAR GISAID METADATA OR GENOMIC EPIDEMIOLOGY METADATA)
download_nr = ifelse(genom_epidem, download_nr_gisaid_genom_epidem_meta, download_nr_gisaid_meta)
metadata_button = download_buttons[[download_nr]] # patient metadata
# TO DO: check available version & if that file is already present in target_dir don't bother downloading it again
metadata_button$clickElement()

# CLICK CHECKBOX NOTICE AND REMINDER OF TERMS OF USE & PRESS DOWNLOAD (THIS ONE DOES NOT ALWAYS SHOW UP)
frames = NULL
while (length(frames)==0) frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)

checkbox_iagree=NULL
while (length(checkbox_iagree)==0) checkbox_iagree = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-event-hook")[[1]]
checkbox_iagree$clickElement() 

Sys.sleep(3)

download_button = NULL
while (length(download_button)==0) download_button = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-form-button")[[2]]
suppressMessages(tryCatch({
  download_button$clickElement() 
}, error = function( err ) { message("") }))

# wait until download finishes
while (length(list.files(target_dir, pattern="crdownload", full.names=T))>=1) {
  Sys.sleep(1)
}

remDr$close()
browser$stop()
remDr$quit()

if (genom_epidem) pat = ".tsv.gz" else pat = ".tar.xz"
df = file.info(list.files(target_dir, pattern=pat, full.names = T))
download = gsub(paste0(target_dir,"/"), "", rownames(df)[which.max(df$mtime)])

message(paste0("Downloaded GISAID metadata file version ", download))

message(paste0("Reading GISAID metadata file version ", download))

if (!genom_epidem) { output = read_tsv( # we directly read from archive
  archive_read(file.path(target_dir,download), file=2), 
  col_types = cols(.default = "c"))
# PS fread is slightly faster (multicore), but requires file to be unzipped first
# system.time(archive_extract(archive=file.path(target_dir,download),
#                 dir=target_dir)) # 33s
# system.time(GISAID <- fread(file.path(target_dir,"metadata.tsv")))
colnames(output) = gsub("-", "_", gsub("?", "", gsub(" ", "_", tolower(colnames(output))), fixed=T), fixed=T)
output$pango_lineage = gsub(" (marker override based on Emerging Variants AA substitutions)", "",  output$pango_lineage, fixed=T)
# for me the regular GISAID metadata package download then has the following column names:
# colnames(output)
# [1] "virus_name"                      "type"                           
# [3] "accession_id"                    "collection_date"                
# [5] "location"                        "additional_location_information"
# [7] "sequence_length"                 "host"                           
# [9] "patient_age"                     "gender"                         
# [11] "clade"                           "pango_lineage"                  
# [13] "pangolin_version"                "variant"                        
# [15] "aa_substitutions"                "submission_date"                
# [17] "is_reference"                    "is_complete"                    
# [19] "is_high_coverage"                "is_low_coverage"                
# [21] "n_content"                       "gc_content" 
} else {
  # system.time(output <- read_tsv( # we directly read from archive
  #   gzfile(file.path(target_dir,download)), 
  #   col_types = cols(.default = "c"))) # 61s
  system.time(output <- tibble(fread( # we directly read from archive, fread 2x faster than read_tsv
    file.path(target_dir,download), 
    colClasses = c("character")))) # 28s
  colnames(output) = tolower(colnames(output))
  # the GISAID genomic epidemiology metadata package download has the following column names:
  # TO DO: make some names consistent across metadata files?
  # colnames(output)
  # [1] "strain"                "virus"                 "gisaid_epi_isl"        "genbank_accession"    
  # [5] "date"                  "region"                "country"               "division"             
  # [9] "location"              "region_exposure"       "country_exposure"      "division_exposure"    
  # [13] "segment"               "length"                "host"                  "age"                  
  # [17] "sex"                   "nextstrain_clade"      "pango_lineage"         "gisaid_clade"         
  # [21] "originating_lab"       "submitting_lab"        "authors"               "url"                  
  # [25] "title"                 "paper_url"             "date_submitted"        "purpose_of_sequencing"
} 
if (clean_up) unlink(file.path(target_dir,download))

return(output)

}


# example
# GISAID = download_GISAD_meta(target_dir = "C:/TEMP")
```

This download package will not contain the records uploaded over the last few days.

You can check the maximum submission date in the download package using

```
GISAID_max_submdate = as.Date(max(GISAID$submission_date, na.rm=T))
GISAID_max_submdate
```

and get the GISAID access IDs of the recently uploaded records using

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("Wytamma/GISAIDR")
library(GISAIDR)
credentials = login(username = Sys.getenv("GISAIDR_USERNAME"),
                    password = Sys.getenv("GISAIDR_PASSWORD"),
                    database = "EpiCoV")
# dataframe with recently uploaded records
# (not included in metadata download package)
recent_records = as.vector(query(
  credentials = credentials, 
  from_subm = as.character(GISAID_max_submdate), 
  to_subm = as.character(as.Date(Sys.time())+1),
  fast = TRUE
))$accession_id
length(recent_records)
recent_records = recent_records[!recent_records %in% GISAID$accession_id] # do not keep record IDs already present in download package
length(recent_records)
```

These extra records you can then download using

```
d_extra = download_GISAID_records(accession_ids = recent_records,
                                  get_sequence=FALSE, 
                                  clean_up=FALSE,                                  target_dir=getwd(),
                                  max_batch_size=10000, # maximum batch size, usually either 10000 or 5000
                                  headless = FALSE,
                                  usr=Sys.getenv("GISAIDR_USERNAME"),
                                  psw=Sys.getenv("GISAIDR_PASSWORD"))
```

And you can merge the GISAID download package & recently submitted records using :

```
library(dplyr)
GISAID = dplyr::bind_rows(GISAID, d_extra)
```

This is using these couple of functions:

```
library(locatexec)

# function to download given records, after having logged in first
# (max batch of 10 000 records at a time)
downl_records = function (accession_ids,
                          get_sequence=FALSE, 
                          clean_up=FALSE,
                          target_dir,
                          remDr=remDr) {
  require(readr)
  require(dplyr)
  require(stringr)
  require(dplyr)
  
  remDr$refresh()
  
  # click Select tab at the bottom
  select_tab = NULL
  while(length(select_tab)==0) select_tab = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-form-button")[[2]]
  select_tab$clickElement()
  
  # enter desired GISAID access nrs in input field 
  frames=NULL
  while (length(frames)==0) frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
  remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
  remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)
  
  # write accession IDs to file & select them via Choose file...
  IDfile = file.path(target_dir,"IDs.csv")
  write.csv(accession_ids, IDfile, row.names=F) # make temporary file with IDs
  # clear input field
  input_field = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-form-fi-multiline")[[2]]
  input_field$clickElement()
  input_field$clearElement()
  
  remDr$refresh()
  
  frames=NULL
  while (length(frames)==0) frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
  remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
  remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)

  frames=NULL
  while (length(frames)==0) frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
  remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
  remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)
  
  file_field = remDr$findElements("name", "data")[[1]]
  file_field$sendKeysToElement(list(IDfile))
  
  unlink(IDfile) # remove temporary file with IDs again
      
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  # click OK
  remDr$refresh()
  
  frames=NULL
  while (length(frames)==0) frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
  remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
  remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)
  
  OK_button = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-form-button")[[2]]
  OK_button$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(1) # TO DO change to while loop
  
  # click OK again to Message XXX entries selected
  buttonid = ""
  while (buttonid=="") {
    html = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
    buttonid = str_extract(html, "(?<=button id=\")[0-9]*") # button id appears dynamic
    # print(buttonid)
  }
  OK_button = remDr$findElement("id", buttonid)
  OK_button$clickElement()
  
  # click Download at the bottom
  remDr$refresh()
  download_tab = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-form-button")[[4]]
  download_tab$clickElement()
  # Sys.sleep(20) # TO DO change to while loop
  
  # select Patient status metadata checkbox
  frames=NULL
  while (length(frames)==0) {
    suppressMessages(tryCatch({
      frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
    }, error = function( err ) { frames = NULL }))
    }
  remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
  remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  checkbox_metadata = NULL
  while (length(checkbox_metadata)==0) { 
    suppressMessages(tryCatch({
      checkbox_metadata = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-event-hook")[[4]]
    }, error = function( err ) { checkbox_metadata = NULL }))
  }
  checkbox_metadata$clickElement() 
  
  # click Download
  mostrecenttsv = suppressWarnings(max(file.info(list.files(target_dir, pattern=".tsv", full.names=T))$mtime))
  Sys.sleep(1) # TO DO change to while loop
  mostrecenttsv_new = mostrecenttsv
  download_button = NULL
  while (length(download_button)==0) {
    suppressMessages(tryCatch({
      download_button = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-form-button")[[2]]
      download_button$clickElement() 
    }, error = function( err ) { download_button = NULL }))
  } 
  
  # CLICK CHECKBOX NOTICE AND REMINDER OF TERMS OF USE & PRESS DOWNLOAD (THIS ONE DOES NOT ALWAYS SHOW UP)
  frames=NULL
  while (length(frames)==0) {
    suppressMessages(tryCatch({
      frames = remDr$findElements("tag name", "iframe")
    }, error = function( err ) { frames = NULL }))
  }
  remDr$switchToFrame(frames[[1]])
  remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10)
  
  checkbox_iagree=NULL
  while (length(checkbox_iagree)==0) checkbox_iagree = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-event-hook")[[1]]
  checkbox_iagree$clickElement() 
  
  Sys.sleep(3)
  
  download_button = NULL
  while (length(download_button)==0) download_button = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-form-button")[[2]]
  suppressMessages(tryCatch({
    download_button$clickElement() 
  }, error = function( err ) { message("") }))
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  # wait until download finishes
  while (mostrecenttsv_new==mostrecenttsv) {
    mostrecenttsv_new = suppressWarnings(max(file.info(list.files(target_dir, pattern=".tsv", full.names=T))$mtime))
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
  df = file.info(list.files(target_dir, pattern=".tsv", full.names = T))
  download = rownames(df)[which.max(df$mtime)]
  
  message(paste0("Downloaded GISAID metadata file ", download))
        
  # read in .tsv file download
  output = read_tsv(download, 
                    col_types = cols(.default = "c"))
  
  colnames(output) = gsub(" ", "_", tolower(colnames(output)))
  colnames(output)[which(colnames(output) %in% c("lineage"))] = "pango_lineage" # code lineage as pango_lineage as in GISAID metadata download package
  output$pango_lineage = gsub(" (marker override based on Emerging Variants AA substitutions)", "",  output$pango_lineage, fixed=T)
  
  if (clean_up) unlink(download)
  
  return(output)
}


# function to download given records
# (will be split in batches of max 10 000 records each)
download_GISAID_records = function(
                            accession_ids,
                            get_sequence=FALSE, 
                            clean_up=FALSE,
                            target_dir=getwd(),
                            max_batch_size=10000, # maximum batch size
                            headless = FALSE,
                            chromedriver_version = as.character(unlist(binman::list_versions("chromedriver")))[grepl(as.character(locatexec::exec_version("chrome")[[1, 1]]), as.character(unlist(binman::list_versions("chromedriver"))))][[1]], # or specify correct version e.g. "104.0.5112.79"
                            usr=Sys.getenv("GISAIDR_USERNAME"),
                            psw=Sys.getenv("GISAIDR_PASSWORD")) {
require(RSelenium)  

if (!dir.exists(target_dir)) dir.create(target_dir)  

arg = c('--no-sandbox', 
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage', 
        '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
        'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
)
if (headless) { arg = c('--headless', arg) } # for headless operation

eCaps = list(chromeOptions = list(
  args = c(#'--headless', # for headless operation
           '--no-sandbox', 
           '--disable-dev-shm-usage', 
           '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
           'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
  ),
  prefs = list(
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads" = 1L,
    "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
    "download.directory_upgrade" = TRUE,
    "safebrowsing.enabled" = TRUE,
    "safebrowsing.disable_download_protection" = TRUE,
    "useAutomationExtension" = FALSE,
    "default_directory" = normalizePath(target_dir)
  )
))
browser = wdman::chrome(port = 4570L, version = chromedriver_version, check = TRUE)
remDr = remoteDriver(port = 4570L, 
                     version = chromedriver_version, 
                     browserName = "chrome", 
                     extraCapabilities = eCaps)
remDr$open()
# code below needed for headless operation
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504731/specify-download-folder-in-rselenium
remDr$queryRD(
  ipAddr = paste0(remDr$serverURL, "/session/", remDr$sessionInfo[["id"]], "/chromium/send_command"),
  method = "POST",
  qdata = list(
    cmd = "Page.setDownloadBehavior",
    params = list(
      behavior = "allow",
      downloadPath = normalizePath(target_dir)
    )
  )
)

message("Downloading GISAID records...")

remDr$navigate("https://www.epicov.org/epi3/start") 
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 100)

# enter credentials
username = NULL
while (length(username)==0) { username = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id='elogin']") }
username$sendKeysToElement(list(usr))
password = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@id='epassword']")
password$sendKeysToElement(list(psw))

# click Login buttom
login_button = remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "//input[@value='Login']")
login_button$clickElement() 

# click EpiCov tab
epicov_tab = NULL
while (length(epicov_tab)==0) { 
  suppressMessages(tryCatch({
    epicov_tab = remDr$findElement("xpath", "//a[contains(text(),'EpiCoV™')]") 
  }, error = function( err ) { epicov_tab = NULL })) }
epicov_tab$click()

# click Search tab
search_tab = NULL
while (length(search_tab)==0) search_tab = remDr$findElements("class", "sys-actionbar-action-ni")[[2]]
search_tab$clickElement()
# Sys.sleep(10) # TO DO add while loop in downl_records

# download records in batches of maximum size max_batch_size

# function to split vector in chunks of max size chunk_length
chunk = function(x, chunk_length=max_batch_size) split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/chunk_length))

batches = chunk(accession_ids)

downloads = do.call(bind_rows, lapply(1:length(batches),
                                  function (batchnr) {
                                    message(paste0("Downloading batch ", batchnr, " out of ", length(batches)))
                                    Sys.sleep(1)
                                    output = downl_records(accession_ids=batches[[batchnr]],
                                                                       get_sequence, 
                                                                       clean_up,
                                                                       target_dir,
                                                                       remDr)
                                    return(output) } ))

remDr$close()
browser$stop()
remDr$quit()

return(downloads)

}
```